# Можно ли открыть сайт-поисковик, как Yandex или Google?

Tags: seo

Можно ли открыть сайт-поисковик, как Yandex или Google? Как можно открыть такие сайты?

Comment: это бесперспективно.

Comment: @Sarvar, поясните вопрос.

Comment: Я хочу открит сайт поисковик. как можно открит? ест какой нибуд способ или учебники или какой нибуд ключавое слова(программа) для поиска?

Comment: Открыть, это в смысле делать такой бизнес ?

Или имеется ввиду задать вопрос такому поисковику из своей программы ?

Comment: Не для бизнеса. Я живу в Узбекистане и у нас нет Узбекский Поисковий сайт. И я хочу открит такой сайт. Это реално или нет???

Comment: Вполне реально) бабло и все будет!

Comment: Ну что вы в самом деле?! :DDD Человек-нуп спрашивает нуп-вопрос...Зачем вам более адекватным людям на него отвечать ? :DD

Answer (score 12):

Можно. 
Для начала, индексируете все (ну или какие захотите) сайты. Сортируете. Записываете куда-нибудь. Потом выбираете (пишите сами?) алгоритм поиска среди этих тонн информации нужных данных. Делаете красивую обертку, вроде странички с полем запроса и кнопкой "Найти". Все.

*Какой вопрос, такой ответ.*

Answer (score 3):

Можете сделать обвертку на Яндексом и Гуглом, по типу Nigma.ru и не изобритать велосипед!

Comment: Это действительно может помочь узбекским друзьям.